# C++ Avoid backslash and double quotes from escaping

Tags: c++

I want to know how to avoid backslash and double-quotes from escaping it's expression. Would using `R()` work with LPCSTR?

Backslash:

```
WriteKey("\"); //this will escaped accidentally.
WriteKey("/"); //this wouldn't
```

Same as double-quotes:

```
WriteKey("""); //this would escape too
WriteKey("'"); //but not this
```

Note: `WriteKey()` would need `LPCSTR` for it's argument

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: the 'mainstream' IDE: Visual Studio

Comment: The raw strings are just normal string literals just like "normal" plain string literals (like e.g. `"foobar"`), the difference is that you don't have to escape some characters.

Comment: my compiler would give me some "missing closing quotes" errors

Comment: Then your compiler maybe doesn't support raw string literals? Which version of Visual Studio do you use? And *how* do you use the raw string literals? Can you show us an example? Code says more than a thousand pictures, and that goes for erroneous code as well. And when asking questions about build errors, include the *complete* (in full and unedited) error output, preferably the whole build log, together with the code that actually generates the errors.

Comment: the latest one: 2015. What do you mean by raw string literals? The `R()` or the `LPCSTR test = """`?

Comment: well, I've stated it already(with the //comment)

Comment: By "raw string literals" I of course mean the `R"delim(...)delim"` variant.

Comment: I think you should learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and you might also want to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: if that, I didn't try it yet. I'm going to try it now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would using `R()` work with LPCSTR?

Yes. Raw string literals produce strings with the same types as their non-raw counterparts.

The following lines pass strings with the same content to `WriteKey`.

```
WriteKey("\\");   // manual escaping
WriteKey(R"(\)"); // raw string literal
```

As you can see, it doesn't make much sense to use raw string literals with very short strings.

Raw string literals are supported in Visual Studio starting with VS2013.

Comment: `WriteKey("\\");` does this would output only `\`?

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan Check the documentation on MS's website [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer, and bonus with the documentation.